# US Playstation Plus code redeemable in EU?

Tags: psn, playstation-plus

I may get my hands on a Amazon.com bought Playstation Plus code. And was wondering if this is redeemable outside the US?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This all depends on what region you bought your code from and what region your PSN account is. If you bought your code from Amazon.com (as opposed to say, Amazon.co.uk/Amazon.de/etc.), then it will be only be redeemable on a North American account, not a European one.

I live in the EU and have European PS3. However, my PSN account is North American, so I can redeem North American codes even though I am physically located in the EU. If you had an EU account on a North American PS3, you'd still only be able to redeem codes that were intended for EU accounts, not NA accounts.

Everything depends on what region your PSN account is set to. If you purchased the code from Amazon.com, then you should be able to use it on a NA account without any problems.

Comment: Thanks. Looks like im setting up an US psn account too then. Any other problems with using a US account in EU?

Comment: Is there any indication that this may change for the PS4? They are not region locked like the PS3 was.

Comment: @RoarG You won't be able to redeem *any* code released for the EU market. That includes PS+ or PSN fund cards sold in EU retail shops and DLCs bundled with games sold in EU retail shops.

Comment: @Nolonar I Undersand, I already got an EU account i been using for years. But since I got my hands on a US PS plus card, I might as well setup an US account. Games downloaded on the US account should be playable on my other user?(Which is linked to an EU account)

Comment: @Reafexus The codes seems to still be region locked on the PS4. Tried on my EU account with no luck.(If code is functioning)

Comment: @RoarG Yes, any content that you download on the US account will be available to your EU account as long as both accounts are on the same machine. I have a US account (with PS+) on my machine and my boyfriend has an EU account (without) and he can play the PS+ stuff I download on my account. Keep in mind that you'll have to keep track of which region you need to get DLC in, as DLC *is* region locked. So if you buy a US version of the game and buy EU DLC for it, that DLC won't be playable when you load up the game. I made that mistake once when I accidentally lost track for a game.

Comment: @FAE Thanks a lot. Nice to hear the money was not wasted.